# onclick on search bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide a container when the search bar is clicked but the page reloads and the container is shown again.

the code is below

```
<div class="search">
        <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="search member..">
            <button class="search_btn">
                <i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

the javascript for adding the class of hide

```
    const search_btn=document.querySelector(".search_btn");
const content=document.querySelector(".content");

search_btn.addEventListener("click", search);

let se=false;
function search(){
    if(!se){
        content.classList.add("hide");
        se=true;
    }else{
        content.classList.remove("hide");
        se=false;
    }
}
```

and the css part of itis as below

```
      .container .content.hide{
    display:none;
  }   
.container .content{  
display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #f2f5f9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page is reloading becase your code contains form and when you are clicking on the search you are actually submit the form. You can use event.preventDefault() for prevent it.

```
function search(event){
    if(!se){
        content.classList.add("hide");
        se=true;
    }else{
        content.classList.remove("hide");
        se=false;
    }
 event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked but i encountered a problem, it is not submitting data

Comment: https://code-boxx.com/submit-form-without-refreshing-page/